# trouble with discord.js shift().toLowerCase(); and not sure why it's not working?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

for some reason my code that stops the bot from being case sensitive doesn't work. I'm not sure why because I can't find anything wrong with it, but capitals don't work. Does someone know why?
This is my code:

```
client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
```

I'm new to discord.js so bear with me. Thank you!

Comment: Are you lowercasing the command trigger aswell?

Comment: I do not understand, do you want just the command to be lowercase, all the args to be lowercase but not the command, or everything to be lowercase?

Answer (score 0):

To make all args lowercase but not the command:

```js
var args = message.content.split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift();
args.forEach((arg, index) => arg[index] = arg[index].toLowerCase());
```

To make everything lowercase:

```js
const args = message.content.toLowerCase().split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift()
```

To make only command lowercase, do what you did there
Perhaps you think that Array.shift returns an array, it only returns what you are removing from the array. So that would make the command lowercase